# SQL statement with CASE WHEN in ORDER BY causes type convert error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Executing the following code triggers an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

All was fine until I have added the second parameter used for sorting purposes.
The code is simplification for clarity.

```
query as String = "
SELECT a, b, c
FROM DataTable
WHERE c = @PARAM
ORDER BY
    CASE @SORTCOLUMN
        WHEN 1 THEN a
        WHEN 2 THEN b
        WHEN 3 THEN c

    END"

Dim param As String = "myprarameter"
Dim sortcolumn as Integer = 1

result = connection.Query(Of MyType)(query, New With {Key .PARAM = param, Key .SORTCOLUMN = sortcolumn})
```

UPDATE:

After hours spent on testing I have narrowed it down to purely SQL issue, not Dapper nor .NET Framework.

Here are my findings:
All works fine until all columns used within `CASE WHEN` are of the same type (or types and even values which can be easily converted into each other). Once types of columns are different and values cannot be converted, it returns type conversion error. Seems it is trying to convert type of the column selected by `CASE WHEN` to the type of the first `WHEN`column.

Herewith two examples. I have removed variables for simplicity.

This works:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TestTable1
(col1 money, col2 money)

INSERT INTO #TestTable1
(col1, col2)
VALUES
(1, 30),
(2, 20),
(3, 10)

SELECT col1, col2
FROM  #TestTable1
ORDER BY
    CASE 2
        WHEN 1 THEN col1
        WHEN 2 THEN col2
    END

DROP TABLE #TestTable1
```

But this does NOT work. Returns:

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TestTable2
(col1 money, col2 varchar(20))

INSERT INTO #TestTable2
(col1, col2)
VALUES
(1, 'cc'),
(2, 'bb'),
(3, 'aa')

SELECT col1, col2
FROM  #TestTable2
ORDER BY
    CASE 2
        WHEN 1 THEN col1
        WHEN 2 THEN col2
    END

DROP TABLE #TestTable2
```

I am using Azure SQL with compatibility level 150.
I have updated Title and Tags accordingly.

UPDATE 2:
I am trying to add a complication to @forpas solution in form of a second parameter which will tell the order. I have used `CASE` within `CASE` but this returns a number of syntax errors.
The `ORDER` part only. The rest has not changed.

```
ORDER BY
CASE @SORTORDER
WHEN 'a' THEN
   (CASE @SORTCOLUMN
        WHEN 1 THEN col1
        WHEN 2 THEN col2
    END,
    CASE @SORTCOLUMN
        WHEN 3 THEN col3
        WHEN 4 THEN col4
    END) ASC
WHEN 'd' THEN
    (CASE @SORTCOLUMN
        WHEN 1 THEN col1
        WHEN 2 THEN col2
    END,
    CASE @SORTCOLUMN
        WHEN 3 THEN col3
        WHEN 4 THEN col4
    END) DESC
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to split the `CASE` statement to as many `CASE` statements needed so each one contains columns with the same or similar convertable data types:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable2
(col1 money, col2 decimal(18, 2), col3 varchar(20))

INSERT INTO #TestTable2
(col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
(1, 5.5, 'cc'),
(2, 1.8, 'bb'),
(3, 3.3, 'aa');

DECLARE @SORTCOLUMN INT = 1; -- 1 or 2 or 3

SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM  #TestTable2
ORDER BY
    CASE @SORTCOLUMN 
      WHEN 1 THEN col1
      WHEN 2 THEN col2 
    END,
    CASE @SORTCOLUMN 
      WHEN 3 THEN col3 
    END

DROP TABLE #TestTable2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3042ac474456755dfddcc698ed79e54e).

Comment: How can I realise `CASE ELSE` scenario in case that the `ELSE` column if one of those from the first `CASE`, so cannot put it as `ELSE` in the last `CASE`, because will trigger same conversion error?

Comment: If the columns are numeric (int, decimal, money) they can be convertable. Don't mix numeric with varchar and date. If you need a final else then instead add one more case statement:  `CASE @SORTCOLUMN WHEN 4 THEN col4 END`

Comment: I have added a complication to the problem - please see UPDATE 2

Answer (score 2):

Simply create the SQL as nvarchar and execute it as follows:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    SELECT a, b, c
    FROM DataTable
    WHERE c = @PARAM
    ORDER BY ' + (CASE @SORTCOLUMN WHEN 1 THEN 'a' WHEN 2 THEN 'b' WHEN 3 THEN 'c' ELSE 'a' END);
EXEC sp_Executesql @SQL,
    N'@Param int',
    @Param = @Param;
```

in VB

```
query as String = "DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT a, b, c FROM DataTable
        WHERE c = @PARAM
        ORDER BY ' + (CASE @SORTCOLUMN WHEN 1 THEN 'a' WHEN 2 THEN 'b' WHEN 3 THEN 'c' ELSE 'a' END);

  EXEC sp_Executesql @SQL,
    N'@Param int',
    @Param = @Param;"
```

Comment: This works, but prefer solution provided by @Forpas

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
query as String = "
SELECT a, b, c
FROM DataTable
WHERE c = @PARAM
ORDER BY
    CASE @SORTCOLUMN
        WHEN '1' THEN a
        WHEN '2' THEN b
        WHEN '3' THEN c

    END"
```

Comment: Does not throw exception, but does not sort either. Is there any way to see the final SQL statement after parameters substitution?

Comment: this is because you set your sortcolumn Dim sortcolumn as Integer = 1, which means it will be sorted by a

Comment: The result does not seem to be sorted by any of the result columns. Changing parameter to `Dim sortcolumn as Integer = 2` doe not make any difference.

Comment: Got it. The 'WHEN' shall look like `WHEN '1' THEN a`. Also noticed that it does not matter if 'sortcolumn' is an `Integer` or `String`. Will mark your answer as accepted as it helped me to sort it out.

Comment: yup, i just realize that 'a' is a column, i updated the answer

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to be more complex and might be not related to SQL syntax but to Dapper, .Net or Visual Studio. Will come back with more insight tomorrow.